# javascript function to save data in global variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems to make this function (addMe) to save the data from img and span from div childBox in two global arrays?
I think something is wrong in the function but can't see what.
This is my [code](http://jsbin.com/ukeWEDO/5/edit?html,css,js,output).

Global var: //before function init

```
var imgSrclist = [];
var imgSpanlist = [];
```

Function:

```
 function addMe(obj) {
var el = document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-img'));

var parent = el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('childBox')[0],
imgSRC = parent.getElementsByName('img')[0].src,
spanTXT = parent.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;

if (obj.checked) {
    imgSpanlist[el.id].imgSrc.push(imgSRC);
    imgSrclist[el.id].imgSpan.push(spanTXT);
} else {
    var imgIx = imgSrclist[el.id].imgSrc.indexOf(imgSRC),
    spanIx = imgSpanlist[el.id].imgSpan.indexOf(spanTXT);
    imgSrclist[el.id].imgSrc.splice(imgIx);
    imgSpanlist[el.id].imgSpan.splice(spanIx);       
        }
 }
```

The data should be saved on global variabels because it will be used later in a new window when you push a button. The script code for the new windows starts with this:

```
var imgSrclist = window.opener.imgSrclist;
var imgSpanlist = window.opener.imgSpanlist;
```

EDIT: The code is now updated, so the arrays is declared. But the problem is that the imgsrc and span text dosen´t comes to the new window. are they saved in the array at all?

Comment: I think you should declare the vars as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I want to mention is;

```
var imgSrclist;
var imgSpanlist;
```

should declare as an array and

```
function init() {

  imgSrc=[]; //Empty array
  imgSpan=[]; //Empty array
}
```

why they are declare as an array as you are not using these as an array.

I have updated two above changes, here is your [code](http://jsbin.com/ukeWEDO/3/edit).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little bit. But the data still does´t saves to the array, the new window just show a white space. humm..

Comment: Hey I don't understand what really you want to do as I check code there is some mistakes again related to declaring variables. You first declare imgSrclist as array then inside init function assign it null. Apart from that I have made changes hopefully this will work for you here is code changes.
http://jsbin.com/ukeWEDO/7/edit